# How to show some elements after hiding everything? Toggling isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Django template

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="{{post.id}}" class="parent{{post.parent_simpler}}"><h3>{{post.post}}</h3>
                <input type = "text" style="display:none;">{% csrf_token %}</input>
                <button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="{{post.id}}" style="display:none;">Add Post.</button>
            </div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$(".jumbotron").click(function(){
          $(".jumbotron").not(this).toggle("slow");
          $("."+ "parent"+this.id).toggle("slow");
        });
```

The first toggle hides all divs of jumbotron class but the second one which is supposed to make the divs with class .parent{{post.parent_post}} visible again is not working.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare class twice in an element but you can space separate as many class names as you want

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="{{post.id}}" class="parent{{post.parent_simpler}}">
```

Should be :

```
<div class="jumbotron  parent{{post.parent_simpler}}" id="{{post.id}}">
```

You can confirm this by inspecting the live html in browser developer tools, only one declaration is being recognized